A memory access marked in EL1-controlled MPU as Device was flushed because it was marked as Normal in EL2-controlled MPU
I'm working on error event from R52 core and I am not able to generate error event 23 (A memory access marked in EL1-controlled MPU as Device was flushed because it was marked as Normal in EL2-controlled MPU).
I have tried to setup region in EL1 MPU that is marked as Device, in EL2 MPU marked as Normal. I have turn on HCR.VM=1 and HSCTLR.M=1 and then I tried to access that memory location (write to it) in EL1. Error event was not registered. Can you please help me to get this error event to work? Is there some special procedure for it? Thank you.
